# Jenkins Built-In Node Heap Size

Tags: jenkins, jvm

I have a Jenkins CI instance running in a Docker Container (Privileged Mode if it makes a difference).
It's been running ok for about a year.
I now have a project which I wouldn't think is that long which is failing to build, the project is just a create-react-app with MUI installed, nothing much extra. Jenkins manages to get through the `npm install` but crashes out on the `npm run build`. When I say crash out - it completely locks up the system.
At first I thought it was the heap size of the JVM because I discovered that was only running at the default. When I adjusted that to 4GB, I was generally able to initially see the process had locked and cancel the build, but the build still couldn't complete itself.
When I look at the system information I can see the memory available is 4GB, but the memory used still never seems to go over about 200MB.
There are no slave nodes, only the built in nodes. I'm wondering if these processes are themselves limited to 200MB? And if so how can I change this.

Already tried building updating the build command to include `--max-old-space=768`.
And in my environment I'm passing:

```
- JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g
- MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx4g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g
```

These are also surfaced in Manage Jenkins -> Manage nodes and clouds -> Built-In Node -> Configure

Nothing seems to have any impact and builds still can't get through the pipeline.
[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: I'm wondering how old java/jdk installation  you are using if you still have `-XX:MaxPermSize` in place

Comment: You also need to describe in more detail what " it completely locks up the system" really means. What do you observe and how? Very high CPU utilization? Is it all consumed by the jenkins process? Is the system completely unresponsive? Or can you use standard OS monitoring tools to observe its behavior? If the process looks stuck maybe you can take a thread dump to see what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for responding @JurajMartinka ! So Java installation is:
`openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.18+10 (build 11.0.18+10, mixed mode)`
To be honest at this point I was just trying any flags that might improve things
Initially before I raised the heap of the JVM overall the entire server locked (it's cloud based and I couldn't even SSH into it). Since raising the heap that has gone away but Jenkins cannot be accessed at all. I need to restart the process to regain access

Comment: What does "Jenkins cannot be accessed at all" means? If you can SSH into the instance, did you try my suggestion with taking a thread dump?

Comment: I just mean the UI becomes completely unresponsive - I need to kill the process and start again. As an example, requesting a thread dump (albeit via the frontend)
`Thread Dump

Failed to retrieve thread dump

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
 at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel$1.get(LocalChannel.java:85)
 at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAllThreadDumps(Jenkins.java:4165)`
Will try again tomorrow via sending kill -3 to the pid and see what comes out

Comment: You can also use jcmd to get a thread dump and various other insights